# Two types of cells in tableView - elegancy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, coding-style

How would you **elegantly** code two types of cell in same tableView?

Obviously I can do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *cellInfo = [_userInformation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellType = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"type"];
if ([cellType isEqualToString:kProfileImage]) {
    ProfileImageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"profileImageCell"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cellLabelText"];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
else {
    AccountCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AccountCell"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cellLabelText"];
    cell.textField.placeholder = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"textFieldPlaceholder"];
    cell.textField.delegate = self;
    cell.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
return nil;
```

But my teacher always tells me not to write something twice, if it happens in both cases, and as you can see, 3 of the lines are same in both cases. I would want to move them outside of the if and only leave the lines that are specific for each case in the if body.

Comment: The answer below is good, but in my opinion, although you shouldn't 'write something twice' the way you have done this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something better by instantiating the cell according to the type, but defining the cell as a UITableViewCell and returning the instance at the end of the method. This would also allow you to write only one line per each common property these cells may share. Something like:

```
UICustomTableViewCell *cell = nil; //This cell type is a common super class of both cell classes
NSDictionary *cellInfo = [_userInformation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellType = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"type"];
if ([cellType isEqualToString:kProfileImage]) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"profileImageCell"];
}
else 
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AccountCell"];
    ((AccountCell*) cell).textField.placeholder = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"textFieldPlaceholder"];
    ((AccountCell*) cell).textField.delegate = self;
    ((AccountCell*) cell).textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
}
cell.delegate = self;
cell.descriptionLabel.text = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cellLabelText"];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
//Any other common properties can by assigned here

return cell;
```

In this example, both cell types have a common "delegate" property.

Comment: But if I do it like that, I won't have access to descriptionLabel / textField, will I?

Comment: Correct, that's why both should inherit from the same custom super class. Updated answer

Comment: Oh, so for this case, I would need to create 3 cell classes. (a superclass, which inherits UITableViewCell and has the shared properties, and two subclasses which inherit the superclass, with custom properties). Yey, you just helped me understand inheritance.

Comment: Also, I should apply a cast in the second case for the cell to access the properties: ((AccountCell*) cell).

Comment: Also true. Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your cell at the beginning as "id" or UITableViewCell.

```
NSDictionary *cellInfo = [_userInformation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellType = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"type"];
UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
if ([cellType isEqualToString:kProfileImage]) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"profileImageCell"];
}
else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AccountCell"];
    cell.textField.placeholder = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"textFieldPlaceholder"];
        cell.textField.delegate = self;
    cell.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
}

cell.descriptionLabel.text = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cellLabelText"];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

return cell;
```

However you may need some type casting in that case if you want to call methods or properties of those custom classes.

```
((AccountCell*) cell).accountCellProperty = @"smth";
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was missing the casting. Least I've learned something more ;). But in that case, I still can't do it, since after the if, I don't which type I need to cast it to (ex: AccountCell / ProfileImageCell), despite them sharing the property.

Comment: The casting may be only done inside "if else" section. If you have some shared properties between those classes I would suggest to make base class MyTableViewCell extends UITableViewCell - and add share properties here - and use this instead of UITableViewCell. And your classes AccountCell should extend MyTableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

**The best way to restructure the above code is:**

```
NSDictionary *cellInfo = [_userInformation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellType = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"type"];
UITableViewCell *aCell = nil;

if ([cellType isEqualToString:kProfileImage]) {
    aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"profileImageCell"];
} else {
    aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AccountCell"];
    ((ProfileImageCell *)aCell).descriptionLabel.text = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cellLabelText"];
    ((ProfileImageCell *)cell).textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;


}

aCell.textField.delegate = self;
aCell.descriptionLabel.text = [cellInfo objectForKey:@"cellLabelText"];
[aCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
return aCell;
```

**Note:** 
*1. You should not use return multiple statements in a method.
2. ((ProfileImageCell *)aCell): this is an easy way to typecast your "aCell" object to "ProfileImageCell" type as "textField" is not a property of UITableViewCell.*

Comment: Yes, but I still can't access aCell.textField after the if statement, since I don't know if I should cast it as ProfileImageCell or AccountCell, despite both having the same property.

Comment: @LordZsolt : I think you are talking about.. aCell.textLabel because UITableViewCell doesn't have textField property.

Comment: Using "aCell.textField" you cannot access "textField" property because, for the compiler, aCell is of type UITableViewCell and "textField" in this case is a property of your custom class. So each time u have to access a custom class method/property u need to do a typecast ((CustomClass *)aCell).property where aCell is an object of type SuperClass of CustomClass.